# WP8 WebBrowser - Play music in the background

Tags: windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

Is there a way by which we can play music in the background when it is launched through a WebBrowser control of Windows Phone 8 (using HTML5 "audio" element)?

I am aware that background tasks are not supported for WebBrowser, but is there a workaround?What are the other options of launching Html and JavaScript code, if not a WebBrowser control? Can it be done using XAML / C# / WPF?

Thanks.

Comment: "...play music in the background when it is launched.." what does 'it' refer to in the question? can you explain the problem?

Answer (score 1):

- I am assuming that you want to open a audio file from webserver / site and want to play it in background on windows phone.
- You can use [AudioPlayerAgent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx) for do that and another thing I found is for steaming audio file from server is [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Audio-Streamer-e85b8deb).
- Check out either of these options. Due to some limitation over more lines of code and code complexity, I can not put code blocks here.
- For launching getting javascript event back to C# , you can use Browser_ScriptNotify and InvokeScript. Other things depend on you business logic. I do not know how your web server is behaving while managing audiofiles.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate to using HTML5/JS, you can use AudioStreamingAgent
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Audio-Streamer-e85b8deb

or

You can use BackgroundAudioPlayer, here is
downloadable sample code: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=219073

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to read this page first, because it includes best practices to follow when you implement background audio in your app:

[Background audio overview for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/hh394039(v=vs.100))

Then you should check this page, it has very detailed explanations and the complete source code for the example applications, where you can see not only the full apss but every piece of code behind every functionality. This should be all the information and source code you need.

[How to play background audio for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/hh202978(v=vs.100))

Of course if you have a more specific question please provide more information and i will provide a detailed explanation.